# Why It's Giving Me Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c

here's the Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main()
{
      
char C1[6] = "Hello";

  char* C2 = C1;

  char C21 = C1[1];


  printf("\n\nC2 in String : %s\n", C2+1 );

  printf("\n\nC2 address : %d\n", C2+1);

  printf("\n example de C2+1 : %s", C21);

}
```

and here's the output

C2 in String : ello

C2 address : 6422273

Segmentation fault

Comment: Does your c compiler not give you a warning? Both clang and gcc show 2 warnings on this code with just the default options.

Comment: By the way, use '%p' to display a pointer value :   printf("\n\nC2 address : %p\n", C2+1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared C21 as a char not char pointer.  Either change the declaration to:

```
char * C21 = &C1[1];
```

or else change %s to %c in the third printf.

If you turn warnings on the compiler will give you a message that lets you work this out for yourself.  All -Wall to your command line if you are using gcc.